# Cannot split content onto a newline in Texmaker

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

[image]

I want the "Since\ e \in \Sigma " part in the image on a new line. So far I have tried "\". "\newline " and "\linebreak" after the end of the first line but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: equation is a single-line environment, use `align` from amsmath for multiple lines, also use `\text{basis step}` never use math italic for words

Answer (score 1):

On of the many solution. I have used the `fleqn` option of `amsmath` to get the assertion on the left. Here there is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
    v\in\Sigma &\text{ so }  v\in P \text{ by "basic steps" } \notag \\
    \text{Since } e\in\Sigma & .
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, is amssymb needed for this MWE?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I put always these package to not do mistakes......ahah. Now I remove it.